# BigSur MacOS beta NetBeans Keyring issue

Tags: netbeans

In Netbeans 12 using BigSur MacOS beta. Does not save SVN password.. its showing exception error is NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.netbeans.modules.keyring.mac.SecurityLibrary

Comment: I think a better place to get support is [NetBeans - User MailingList](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Mailing+lists) or open a bug with some more information and the entire stack trace at [Apache Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was related with the Zulu-JDK.
zulu8.54.0.21-ca-jdk8.0.292-macosx_aarch64

Solution:

Define netbeans_jdkhome in

/Applications/NetBeans/Apache\ NetBeans\ .app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf

Example:

```
...
# Default location of JDK:
.....
#
netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.11.jdk/Contents/Home"
#Out-commented because of class not found problem. 
#netbeans_jdkhome="/Users/glodde/Applications/zulu8.54.0.21-ca-jdk8.0.292-macosx_aarch64"

# Additional module clusters:
```